# How to cut out a polygon shaped part of an image?

Tags: java, image, processing

I have a polygon with the following vertices...

```
20,20
20,30
40,30
```

and an image. I want to cut the polygon shaped part out of the image to form a new one. Is there any algorithm to do so?
I am using Processing if that's anything helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new image and paint the old one on with the clip set.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(20, 20);
path.lineTo(20, 30);
path.lineTo(40, 30);
path.closePath();

g.setClip(path);
g.drawImage(YourOrigioanlImage, 0, 0, null);
```

It looks like in "Processing" you can create a `PImage` from an `java.awt.Image` so you can get your `PImage` by using the code sample above then doing this:

```
PImage pImage = new PImage(image);
```

You can also get a `BufferedImage` object from a `PImage` by casting the `getNative()` method from `PImage`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, I am using Processing, do you know any alternatives for this?

Comment: @EwenW. updated awnser. I looked into doing something similar with Processing but couldnt find anything. Let me know if that helps, I have never used Processing so i'm just shooting in the dark if this works.

Comment: You can also:

Use a PGraphic to draw a mask in shape format and use it to mask the image. 
or
Use Textures, look the TextureTriangle example bundled with Processing (examples>Topics>Textures)